# how to get same realm instance between two activitys?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

```
public class MyApp extends MultiDexApplication {
  private static MyApp instance;

  private static class LazyHolder {
    private static final Realm INSTANCE = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
  }

  public static Realm getRealm() {
    return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
  }

  public static Context getContext() {
    return instance;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    instance = this;
    super.onCreate();
    Realm.init(this);
  }
}
```

this is my application activity.

one recyclerView Adapter is using two activities.

first, normal Article List Activity.
second, find Article List Activity.

when I select an Article with the same Url for any Activity, I want to save the Url for that Article.

And this is how I determine if it's stored in Realm in onBindViewHolder().

```
RealmResults<Article> results = MyApp.getRealm().where(Article.class).equalTo("link", list.get(position).getLink()).findAll();
boolean isSeenArticle = results.size() >= 1;
if(hasKeyword(position)) {
  String[] temp = list.get(position).getTitle().split(keyword);
  setTitleSpannable(holder.title, temp, isSeenArticle);
}
else {
  holder.title.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());
  holder.title.setTextColor(isSeenArticle ? context.getResources().getColor(R.color.OneDarkSemiSemiGray) : context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimary));
}
```

color of the holder.articler_title text changes on one side only.

However, both activities appear to have different Realm Instances.

How can I use the same Realm Instance?

Comment: RealmChangeListener

Comment: @EpicPandaForce addChangeListener in recyclerview adapter?

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/e74afaa416df39a284e4555d84387a62a03d1b42/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.java

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thank you, i found cause. it was not for realm. two activities item has same html, but not same link. so i compared link that only required parts.